# Merge two JSON files in a particular structure

Tags: java, json, shell, npm, jq

I have two json files of the follwoing structure 
**File 1**

```
[
  {
    "line": 2,
    "elements": [
      {}
    ]
  }
]
```

**File 2**

```
[
  {
    "line": 3,
    "elements": [
      {}
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to merge these files such that the output file looks like

**Output File**

```
[
  {
    "line": 2,
    "elements": [
      {}
    ]
  },
 {
    "line": 3,
    "elements": [
      {}
    ]
  }
]
```

I can use npm, java or any shell library

Comment: nodejs would be super easy. Read both files in as json, you'll get two arrays, then just array1.concat(array2) will return a new array containing all elements from both arrays.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to the magic of jq's `-s` command-line option, you can "add" as many files as you like, like so:

```
$ jq -s add file1.json file2.json
```

The underpinning that provides the magic is jq's support for streams. This means, for example, that jq automatically supports JSONL (JSON Lines). The "inverse" of the -s option (i.e., for converting to JSONL) is the -c option.